# Cayley graph of the fundamental group of the 2-torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, cayley-graphs

Does anybody knows some description or some good picture on the internet for the Cayley graph of the fundamental group of the 2-torus, when this is constructed by connected sum of two torus. I know, by van-Kampen theorem, this group is an product of two 2-free groups amalgamated by Z, but I really need to literally see that.

Comment: @EricWofsey Ah, I didn't know the phrase "$n$-torus" has two meanings.

Comment: Maybe it's better to refer to the [genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)#Orientable_surface) of this thing? Do you know the usual presentation of it as $\langle a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2 : [a_1,b_1][a_2,b_2]\rangle$?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for from something as awkward as the Cayley graph that description of $\pi_1 (\Sigma_2)$ as an amalgamated free product wouldn't give you? The usual presentation of $\pi_1(\Sigma_2)$ gives a convenient generating set.

Comment: I just need to see what happens with the Cayley graphs of amalgamated products. This is just an easy example.

Comment: I still don't know what you're trying to get out of this, but you might find something useful in Serre's "Trees."

Comment: I just need to see something on the picture (I don't know what, some kind of pattern). Serre's book is indeed quite useful, but does not have a picture of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like this:

[image]

A closed orientable surface of genus $2$ admits a hyperbolic metric, so corresponds to some quotient of the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}$. The action of the fundamental group on $\mathbb{H}$ can be used to draw a Cayley graph in $\mathbb{H}$. This is what this picture is depicting, in the [Poincaré disk model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model) of $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I'm looking for. My problem with this picture is that becomes too small really fast, so it is not possible to see so much things on that. Do you have another picture? Perhaps on the half-plane model or on the klein disk model.

Comment: This is an amazing picture. How did you generate it?

Comment: @NWMT: Google image search!

Comment: In case anyone else is looking at this hoping for a higher-res version of this, I made one here: https://github.com/geodavic/hyperdraw/blob/main/pi2_nocolor_label.pdf